# My 4 week old kittens are weeing around the room and only using the litter to eat. What should I do?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

My cat has had a litter of 5 beautiful kittens; however now they are 4 and a half weeks old and a few have started urinating around my room but only using the litter provided to eat... I don't know what to do
p.s. The litter is catsan non-clumping litter

Comment: Do you mean your kittens are eating the litter?? I would think that would be very bad for them but maybe I don't understand your question correctly.

Comment: Please explain what the kitten are doing in or with the clumping cat sand.

Answer (score 3):

Kittens will eat litter sometimes. I believe catsan is a clay / silica based litter, which is bad for cats, people, flooring etc. It is dangerous for them to eat. I would shred some paper or look for a safer litter. Your vet may have some suggestions.

Just out of curiosity is their mother still around? 8 weeks is the normal recommended time they should spend with mom so they learn how to be proper cats. Does their mother use the litter box they are supposed to use? If they can watch their mother and see how and where she goes they may do the same.